# vi editor showing bracket date and time stamp on left hand side

Tags: linux, editor, vi

I am fairly new to Linux and am trying to edit a file in the vi editor.  when I access the file, I have date and time strings running down the left hand side and it makes it very cumbersome to edit the file.  any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Ummm ... are those part of the file? Or are you suggesting vi puts them there?

Comment: Are you editing a logfile with each line starting with a timestamp? And what do you want to do with the file? Perhaps you want to `grep` certain lines from the file, `cut` from a position or remove substrings with `sed` using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Since vi/vim doesn't insert dates by default, this strongly suggests that the dates are in the data itself.  You have several choices that occur to me:

1. You can delete the dates from the actual file content with something like `:%s/^\d\{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s*` (assuming the dates are in "`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`" format)
2. With a recent version of vim (check the output of `:version` for `+conceal`) you can leave the dates in the file but have them hidden unless you're on the actual line:

   ```
   :set conceallevel=2
   :syn match Comment /^\d\{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s*/ conceal
   ```